# Хотел бы спросить правильный алгоритм кода к этой задаче?

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Написать программу, которая создает копию txt файла, который содержит действительные числа, но сначала идут положительные элементы, затем нулевые, а в конце отрицательные.

```
void main()
    {
        char ch[80];
        ifstream in("text1.txt");
        if (!in) {
            cout << "fail" << endl;
        }
        ifstream fin("text1.txt");
        if (in)
        {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                i++; 
                if (i > 0) {
    
                }
                if (i < 0) {
    
                }
               in.eof();
            } while (!in.eof());
    
            ofstream fout("text1_copy.txt");
            fout << fin.rdbuf();
            fout.close();
            fin.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже задолбали этой задачей с разных аккаунтов...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> pos, neg;
    int zeros = 0;
    double x;

    for(ifstream in("text.txt"); in >> x; )
    {
        if (x > 0) pos.push_back(x);
        else if (x < 0) neg.push_back(x);
        else zeros++;
    }

    ofstream out("text_copy.txt");
    for(double x : pos) out << x << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < zeros; ++i) out << 0.0 << "\n";
    for(double x : neg) out << x << "\n";
}
```

Формат вывода (в строку, табличкой, количество знаков), защиту от дурака (нет файла, в нем не числа) - допишите сами.

Comment: Почему идут положительные элементы затем нулевые а затем снова положительные?

Comment: Откуда ж мне знать? У меня положительные, нули, отрицательные... Вот, только что из `1
2
3
-4
-5
0
0
3
4
-23
-1.5` получилось `1
2
3
3
4
0
0
-4
-5
-23
-1.5`

Comment: А этот код можно реализовать без векторов?

Comment: Можно и без векторов.

Comment: А если нужно сделать с использованием файловых указателей то ifstream заменить f1 = fopen ( "Text1.in", "rt")?

Comment: Блин, еще когда вы под другим ником с этой задачей носились, я писал, что надо давать **точное  задание**. Ваше "дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде" ничего, кроме раздражения, не вызывает. Пока не будет абсолютно точного задания - я отказываюсь что-либо делать. Того, что я написал, вполне достаточно.